# How to extract everything after parentheses in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, regex, split, google-bigquery

How can I extract all the characters after the first word?

For example, I would like to have `(084M)` in its own column with the parentheses included. I've tried to [`SPLIT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split) and [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) but I have ran into issues.

**Table**:

| Name |
| --- |
| Elizabeth (084M) |
| Elizabeth (084M) |
| Elizabeth (084M) |
| Pittston (14KN) |
| Pittston (14KN) |
| Pittston (14KN) |
| Cheektowaga (14ON) |

**Image of Table**:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below

```
select *,
  regexp_extract(name, r'\w+\s+(.+)')
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
select *,
  SPLIT(name, ' ')[OFFSET(1)]
  from data
```